# Best subset selection with categorical data

Tags: r, categorical-data, feature-selection, stepwise-regression

I am studying a dependent variable `Y` with 4 predictors: 2 of them are categorical (with 6 and 7 levels) and 2 numeric.

I have used the best subset selection for choosing among the different models. Using `RSS`, `Adjusted R^2`, `Cp` and `BIC`, I have built the following figures as function of the number of variables:

[image: Selection of variables for the best model with a given number of predictors]

Now I have 2 questions:

1. After adding 7 variables, the model seems to stabilize; even though the "best" number of variables given by RSS, Cp, AdjR^2 and BIC is higher, am I allowed to choose 7 as a good number of variables? (The red dots in the figures indicate the best number of variables predicted by the various RSS, BIC etc...)
2. The best subset model take into account some levels of the categorical predictors, leaving out some others. What is the interpretation of that? If for example I choose a model with 7 independent variables, using the R command `regsubsets` I can print the coefficients of my model. I am also aware of the fact that either I take all the levels of a categorical feature either none of them. But how keep low the number of predictors if I am obliged, at the end, to take all the levels into account? And what coefficients should I use for the other levels? Am I finally obliged to choose one of the highest possible number of variables?

Comment: What do you mean "the model seems to stabilize?"

Comment: I would love to know how you created those excellent graphs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the poster used `regsubsets` from the package `leaps`, but apparently said package is not appropriate for working with quantitative variables.

See question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64167138/regsubsets-is-generating-dummy-variables-from-factor-levels-can-we-make-it-not for a better answer.

[This was posted as an answer because I do not have enough reputation for commenting]